# How to run image in emulator which throws read only flag

Tags: android, dns, android-emulator, android-source

I am using aosp 10 where customized hardware been used from renases.

Now in prebuilds I found there is emulator which is in prebuild path.

prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/emulator

So when I use the command

mydroid$ emulator

i get error as

/mydroid/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/emulator64-crash-service

```
emulator: Increasing RAM size to 2048MB
emulator: VM heap size 48MB is below hardware specified minimum of 192MB,setting it to that value
emulator: System image is read only
emulator: Found 1 DNS servers: 127.0.1.1
emulator: ERROR: Running multiple emulators with the same AVD is an experimental feature.
Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature.
```

I used adb-kill-server but still I couldn't resolve this error.

Comment: I faced with the same issue when my previous emu process wasn't finished correctly. Try to reboot and run once more.

Comment: You mean in command, I need to give reboot?

Comment: Reboot pc. Sometimes qemu is not correctly finished.
Also, might be some issues if you are under usual user trying to start emu but previous emulator was started under root user.
Frankly speaking, i would rebuild standard android google goldfish (for cuttlefish i faced with different issues in start) emulator and try to run the build emu. Could help.